# How to keep data when changing styles in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a map of geojson facility points located in Alaska. I want to allow the user to switch between a regular and satellite view. Upon clicking satellite, the loaded geojson data disappears.

I have tried reinstatiating the code, but I realize I do not know how to do that properly. Otherwise, im not sure what the solution is.

I have a working plunker here
https://plnkr.co/edit/FyrsbMRJp6vuI3jRt8XL?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
  integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
  crossorigin=""/>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>BR Live Cluster Map</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.54.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.54.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
  crossorigin=""></script>

    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }


        #menu {
        position: absolute;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>

  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.3.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.3.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css' />

<div id='map'></div>
<div id='menu'>
<input id='streets-v11' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='streets' checked='checked'>
<label for='streets'>streets</label>
<input id='satellite-v9' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='satellite'>
<label for='satellite'>satellite</label>
</div>

<script>


mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZHlhdnJvbSIsImEiOiJjamZsZGl0dnIwMHUwMnhvNDB4N2o0cnB6In0.AqxOgFJXuLgFMiwkPutaLA';
if (!mapboxgl.supported()) {
alert('Your browser does not support Mapbox GL');
} else {
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    //style: 'mapbox://styles/dyavrom/cji1rn1tz00x02sqtervd1sq0',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [-153.59179687498357, 65.66995747013945],
    zoom: 3.5
});
}

var layerList = document.getElementById('menu');
var inputs = layerList.getElementsByTagName('input');

function switchLayer(layer) {
var layerId = layer.target.id;
map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/' + layerId);
}

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
inputs[i].onclick = switchLayer;
}




map.on('load', function() {
    // Add a new source from our GeoJSON data and set the
    // 'cluster' option to true. GL-JS will add the point_count property to your source data.
    map.addSource("BRdata", {
        type: "geojson",
        // Point to GeoJSON data. This example visualizes all M1.0+ BRdata
        // from 12/22/15 to 1/21/16 as logged by USGS' Earthquake hazards program.
        data: "data.geojson",
        cluster: true,
        clusterMaxZoom: 14, // Max zoom to cluster points on
        clusterRadius: 50 // Radius of each cluster when clustering points (defaults to 50)
    });



    map.addLayer({
        id: "clusters",
        type: "circle",
        source: "BRdata",
        filter: ["has", "point_count"],
        paint: {
            // Use step expressions (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-step)
            // with three steps to implement three types of circles:
            //   * Blue, 20px circles when point count is less than 100
            //   * Yellow, 30px circles when point count is between 100 and 750
            //   * Pink, 40px circles when point count is greater than or equal to 750
            "circle-color": [
                "step",
                ["get", "point_count"],
                "#51bbd6",
                100,
                "#f1f075",
                2000,
                "#f28cb1"
            ],
            "circle-radius": [
                "step",
                ["get", "point_count"],
                20,
                100,
                30,
                750,
                40
            ]
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        id: "cluster-count",
        type: "symbol",
        source: "BRdata",
        filter: ["has", "point_count"],
        layout: {
            "text-field": "{point_count_abbreviated}",
            "text-font": ["DIN Offc Pro Medium", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
            "text-size": 12
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        id: "unclustered-point",
        type: "circle",
        source: "BRdata",
        filter: ["!", ["has", "point_count"]],
        paint: {
            "circle-color": "#11b4da",
            "circle-radius": 4,
            "circle-stroke-width": 1,
            "circle-stroke-color": "#fff"
        }
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hoping that when you click satellite, the new view enters as well as the geojson.

Comment: Hi Deeba,
Please post the relevant minimal reproducible example code in your question, don’t post it somewhere else on the internet; make it easy for people to help you and you’ll get more and better answers. How to post a Stack Snippet (in your question): meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/7515189

Comment: Search the mapbox-gl-js github issues there is some examples there.

Comment: When you change styles in Mapbox, the layers are "updated", in Leaflet for example, you have a "basemap" and the "layers" being diferent things, in mapbox that's doesn't happen, it's all "layers" in a way, what you should do is before changing styles, store your polygons, your points, etc, and re-add them in the map after the style finished loading